# MSBuild Extension Pack FxCop - Using Ruleset switch

Tags: fxcop, msbuildextensionpack

I'm trying to specify a ruleset instead of rules assembly as part of the fxcop msbuild task, but its not currently working. The documentation says it does support this.

http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.11.0/html/a111be65-19a8-05e0-5787-c187c3ee65f2.htm

so I've declared the build task like below...

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.FxCop
        TaskAction="Analyse"
        Ruleset="C:\FxCop\test.ruleset"
        Files="@(FXCopAssemblies)"
        OutputFile="$(PathCheckout)FXCop\fxcopreport.xml"
        LogToConsole="true"
        DependencyDirectories="@(DependencyDirectories)"/">
```

but the msbuild output returns the following error

```
error MSB4064: The "Ruleset" parameter is not supported by the
"MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.FxCop" task. Verify the parameter exists   
on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
```

I have version 4 of the MS Build Extension Pack 4.0 so it should already contain the following fxcop tasks.